# How to bind the data in treeview with sqldatasource

Tags: c#, treeview

I have data in following two tables

`Parent Mater` and `Child Master`

In `parent master` there are two fields `prtID` and `name`. In `child master` there are three fields `ID`, `name` and `prtid`, The **prtid** is foreign key from `parent master`.

I want to bind data with `TreeView` in a windows application in c#.net 
such that each child will appear inside its parent node.

Can please guide me to right direction for this task?

Comment: Anything that you have tried? Some working or not working code may be ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate entry. Please do some search before making a new question :

- [Bind C# Windows Form TreeView from DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181371/bind-c-sharp-windows-form-treeview-from-database)